# How to create a link to a specific section/paragraph in github flavored markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I have a document written in markdown (for github pages) and I am trying to create an internal link to the start of a specific paragraph. So that later in the document I can have the user click and jump directly back to the point in the document. How to I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is easy
'[Types]'(#types)'

'## Types'
// without quotes

real example you can see [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/README.md)
just push on the pen for showing 'md' markup